# Issues Specifying XML Schema in Visual Studio with Relative Path When Path Contains Hash (#)

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd

I store my C# projects under a folder called "C#". I have discovered however that when an XML file and its accompanying schema are stored under this folder, Visual Studio fails to locate the file specified to noNamespaceSchemaLocation. Instead, it looks for the parent folder of the folder whose name contains a hash.

For example, given the following XML and Schema

```xml
<!-- XMLFile1.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="XMLSchema1.xsd" bar="bar"/>
```

```xml
<!-- XMLSchema1.xsd -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Foo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

stored in C:\Programming\C#\Project\, Visual Studio will complain that the XMLSchema1.xsd file doesn't exist under C:\Programming. If you specify the absolute path to the xsd however, or simply move the project out of the C# folder, it works fine.

What's up with this behavior? Or more precisely, is there anything that can be done to workaround this without having to move files somewhere else? From doing a bit of research it appears the issue here it might be that # is considered the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier); that's all very interesting, however ideally I'd like to signal somehow that my # should be simply read as-is. As this is an open source project, I can't be making any absolute references to where *I'm* storing the files.

Comment: Your assessment of the problem seems to be correct. Having `#` in the path makes the XML parser think that the parent directory of the one with `#` in the name is the current directory, so it searches relative to that one if you use a relative path. I'm not sure if there is a way to get around that other than using absolute paths or avoiding `#` in your path names.

Comment: I don't know the details of what VS does, but you need to be very careful not to assume that file names and URIs are interchangeable. Software is often liberal in accepting filenames where you should really be supplying a URI, but that liberality probably won't extend to characters like "#" that have a special meaning in URIs. Such characters should be escaped using %HH encoding.